# Drupal export statistics

Tags: drupal, statistics, export

I'm using the Statistics module with Better Statistics module in Drupal 7. Now I have several pages of statistics that I'd like to export as an Excel, CSV or PDf. Is there a way I can do it? Is there a module or any specific database table I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the [views data export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module may be what you are after; it can generally be used to export all fields in a particular view. I'm not sure if it will work with the statistics module, though.